# how to replace a part of string when it contains a metacharacter in perl

Tags: regex, perl, replace, escaping, metacharacters

I have strings that look like this for example `subnet 1 ims-0-x ip address`

and I want to get rid of the `-x` so it will be `subnet 1 ims-0 ip address`

I tried doing this regex replace

```
$string=~ s/\\-x//;
```

which is not working. I think my issue is that I am not escaping the dash properly. please help me fix that one line.

Comment: Please provide your exact code and also give exactly what is the output that you are getting.

Comment: `perl -e '$s="subnet 1 ims-0-x ip address"; $s =~ s/\-x//; print $s;'` works. If that's not the actual string you're using and is a fabricated/stripped example, please post the original string with perhaps the IPs changed. You could be getting caught up with what is contained in the original string. For example... if the "-x" actually contains special characters, you may not be escaping them properly.

Comment: FYI: double-backslash in a regex is a literal blackslash (i.e. a literal backslash in the input) and `-` isn't special in this context: within a regex a hyphen is only special in between `[` and `]` (and only if it isn't first or last).

Comment: it had one back slash escaping the dash, when i typed one back slash it did not show up on stackoverflow for some reason. so i typed two back slashes and then it only showed 1. but now i see two there.... not sure why. but yes its supposed to say s/\-x// ;

Answer (score 1):

You are escaping a backslash and not the dash. With two backslashes (`\\`), the first backslash escapes the second and it looks for a backslash in the string. It should be `s/-x//`. You don't need to escape the `-`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = "subnet 1 ims-0-x ip address";
$s =~ s/-x//;
print "$s\n"
```

Comment: I do not see any difference between your regex and one given in question.

Comment: I took out the first backslash that was escaping another backslash... Then in an edit I removed both backslashes because it isn't necessary to escape the dash...

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and its working fine, /g is to replaceAll instances.
The output is "subnet 1 ims-0 ip address"

```
$string = "vishwassubnet 1 ims-0-x ip address";
$string =~ s/-x//g;
print $string;
```

https://ideone.com/9zh91T